# Is there a file system that can mount the same block device in a VM and host?

Tags: filesystems, virtualization

Is there such a file system ? My goal is to have a shared file system between a host and a VM with native performances.

I want to avoid vboxfs, network file systems, etc.

Comment: You mean that both host and guest need to update in parallel the same disk with similar performance? This may only work with a Hyper-V Generation 2 VM, where host and guest are recent Windows versions, since then the guest disk driver is only a stub to the host's driver.

Comment: See also: https://serverfault.com/questions/266759/open-source-shared-storage-file-system

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**: No, this is not possible.

An operating system (OS) is - among other things - being responsible to manage hardware resources. Mounting a file system stored at a block device implies that the operating system manages this block device.

Imagine there would be two OS's running in parallel and both try to write a file at the same time. This would result in both OS's writing data at the same time and thereby destroying probably both files.

Hence, you need at least one additional layer of abstraction. This could be a bind mount, a network filesystem or a filesystem managed by your hypervisor.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your goal is for both host and guest to share a disk in
parallel, where both have very similar performance on disk access.

While
[Open-source Shared Storage file systems](https://serverfault.com/questions/266759/open-source-shared-storage-file-system)
do exist, they do usually introduce overheads such as network access,
so adding some degradation of the performance.

Achieving true similarity of performance for both host and guest may only be
possible using Hyper-V Generation 2 virtual machines.
This generation requires recent Windows versions and achieves better integration
of the virtual disk driver with the physical host.
Using shared folders between host and guest is then probably the closest you
can come to your goal.

For more information see:

- [Generation 2 Virtual Machine Overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn282285(v=ws.11))
- [Should I create a generation 1 or 2 virtual machine in Hyper-V?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/plan/should-i-create-a-generation-1-or-2-virtual-machine-in-hyper-v)

I remark that although the documentation for Generation 2 VM specifies as
the minimum requirements the versions Windows Server 2012 and Windows 8.1,
using only the latest Windows versions might give better results.